# php code for image fetching

Tags: post-thumbnails

```
<?php 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxxxx", "xxxxx") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("xxxxx") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT
    p1.*,
    wm2.meta_value
FROM
    xxxxx_posts p1
LEFT JOIN
    xxxxxx_postmeta wm1
    ON (
        wm1.post_id = p1.id
        AND wm1.meta_value IS NOT NULL
        AND wm1.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
    )
LEFT JOIN
    xxxxx_postmeta wm2
    ON (
        wm1.meta_value = wm2.post_id
        AND wm2.meta_key = '_xxxxxx_attached_file'
        AND wm2.meta_value IS NOT NULL
    )
WHERE
    p1.post_status='publish'
    AND p1.post_type='post'
ORDER BY
    p1.post_date DESC") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 Print "<div class='widgetlist'>";
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 {  


Print "<ul><li><a href='http://xxxxxxx.com/en/?p=".$info['ID'] . "'>";

Print $info['post_title'];
Print "</a> </li></ul> "; 

 } 
 Print "</div>";
 ?>
```

How to fetch the featured image in wordpress post //////

Comment: Can you please try to clean up your code syntaxing? It is hard to understand what you are getting at.

Answer (score 0):

To get a featured image use `the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr );`.

Both `$size` and `$attr` are optional, they are usually defined within the theme.

If they are not you can just set the as following:

```
$default_attr = array( 
    'src'   => $src,
    'class' => "attachment-$size",
    'alt'   => trim(strip_tags( $attachment->post_excerpt )),
    'title' => trim(strip_tags( $attachment->post_title ))
);
$size = array( 32, 32 );
```

P.s.: I hope this is what you are looking for, the code that you have posted does not make a lot of sense. What do you want to do?

Comment: Additional information should be edited into the body of the answer, not inserted into a comment.

Answer (score 0):

> How to fetch the featured image in wordpress post[?]

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id );
```

Or, inside a proper Loop,

```
the_post_thumbnail();
```

But I have a feeling that there is information missing from the question. You aren't using any Core functions and there is no explanation why, or reasons why not.

For example, [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) would be far easier that cooking up your own SQL. Using the [`$wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) object would be easier than making your own MySQL connection. Using [`get_permalink`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) is easier and more reliable than creating a link manually.

## Reference

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail